# How to Save Sverchok nodes

Tags: sverchok

I'm new to Sverchok and I don't quite understand how to work with it.
I watched lot's of videos but none of them showed how to include Sverchok in the Blender workflow.
I created some nodes and successfully generated objects with it.
I saved my Blender file and quit. The next time I opened the file, the generated objects were there but I can't find the Sverchok node structure anymore and so I'm not able to further tweak the generated objects.

**(1)** How do I save a Sverchok Node Structure?

**(2)** Is it not saved inside the Blender File?

**(3)** Does it stays connected to the generated objects after reopening the file?

Sorry for the newbie questions and thanks for any suggestion.

BR Steve

Comment: In the middle of the top bar of the sverchok node creation area, you need topick the right node graph from the drop down list, just as in the material editor.

It is saved in the Blender file and should work after reopening your scene, however updating to a new sverchok version can break stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar happens with Materials/node trees that are not used by any objects (ie - don't have "users". Objects produced by Sverchok don't automatically make those objects a *user* of a Sverchok node tree. You might need to press the "F" icon in the nodetree header toolbar (or Shield icon in 2.8+), to add a fake user to the node tree, then save.

The issue is Old. We discuss this on the Sverchok issue tracker back in 2014 - https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/356 )